# How to set up alias to cd into a subdirectory with completions?

Tags: zsh, directory, autocomplete

I've set up this function in my `~/.zshrc`:

```
cdp() {
  cd "/mnt/c/Users/Mark/PhpstormProjects/$1"
}
```

But I don't get tab completions for it. Is there any way to get the directory names to autocomplete when I tab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a [completion function](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#Completion-System) for `cdp`. Conventionally, the function is called `_cdp`. You can define it in your `.zshrc` and assign it explicitly with [`compdef`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-compdef).

```
_cdp () {
  … # code goes here
}
compdef _cdp cdp
```

Alternatively, put the completion code in a file in your `$fpath` called `_cdp` with a [completion autoload directive](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#Autoloaded-files).

```
#compdef cdp
… # code goes here
```

To complete directories, use [`_files -/`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-_005ffiles). To complete directories relative to a different place from the current directory, use [the `-W` option](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-_005fpath_005ffiles). Since this function only takes one argument, [only complete the first argument](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-Widgets.html#index-CURRENT).

```
_cdp () {
  ((CURRENT == 2)) &&
  _files -/ -W /mnt/c/Users/Mark/PhpstormProjects
}
```

---

Instead of this function, you may or may not prefer to add the directory to [`cdpath`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#index-cdpath).

```
cdpath+=/mnt/c/Users/Mark/PhpstormProjects
```

Comment: FYI, it should be `((CURRENT == 2))` to complete only the first arg. I'm guessing 1 is the command itself.